# Deleting windows 8 and clean install ubuntu on ssd/hdd hybrid

Tags: system-installation

I hope this isn't a duplicate but all the question asked what to keep windows 8. I want to completely remove windows and install Ubuntu. Using [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DQGBABI) ultra book. ( the ASUS VivoBook S400CA-RSI5T18 14-Inch Touchscreen Ultrabook)

Question one: can I just do a plain install ubuntu over windows option or will I need to install it manually? in order to install the / on the ssd and the home on the hdd

Question two: will I need the swap partition?

Question three: what version would be best for me 12.04 lts or( 13.10 then when it comes out 14.04)

Will constantly be checking for answers. Thank in advance

Comment: I do not understand the downgrades? Seems like legimate questions as an install removing Windows on an Ultrabook has several special issues. I really suggest dual booting first to make sure Ubuntu works without issue. You need to remove RAID meta-data from Intel SRT, and may have video driver issues with the dual video. Better to use newest version as it has more updates or this month's 12.04.4 version. Many come back after erasing Windows and want that one app. So best to fully back it up if deleting.

Comment: I downvoted because of the amazon link which I originally thought to be a referral link, hence assuming the whole question is a ruse. Well, I can't take it back unless op edits hsi post. But also, op is asking 3 questions. And except for linking terminal/bash output, as far as I am aware it's common to put all the info in the op (such as the notebook model name). Plus the first question certainly can be solved with gooling for about 20 seconds I reckon.

Comment: I have searched Google, I even went to the second and third page! But everyone with a hybrid sdd/hdd wants to dualboot. I want to completly remove windows and install ubuntu.

Comment: @joe ask it  as another question.

Comment: @henry, you'll need to get used to Amazon links ;) Canonical and Amazon are best buds.

Comment: @vasa1 True. I took back my downvote, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question one: can I just do a plain install ubuntu over windows option or will I need to install it manually?

Make a back up of important datas and select the option install ubuntu over windows.

> Question two: will I need the swap partition?

[How much swap do I need?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#How_much_swap_do_I_need.3F)

> Question three: what version would be best for me 12.04 lts or( 13.10 then 14.04)

For extended support,
choose Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

For the latest features,
choose Ubuntu 13.10

Ubuntu 14.04 stable version was not yet released.

Comment: when I select the option install over windows will it put the / in the ssd and the home in the hdd?

Comment: no,for manually setting the `/` and `home` partition you had to select `something else` option.

Comment: I see. But for the swap space the link you sent said "High RAM and high disk space With 2 GiB RAM and 100 GB hard disk, use 2 GiB for swap since hard disk space is plentiful." I have 4 GiB of ram and 500 Gib of harddisk space. Should I allocate 2 GiB or 4?

Comment: 2 GB is enough.